# How to save downloaded csv file to specified directory using php

Tags: php, csv

I am using php script to download data from database and export it into CSV format.I can generate the file but only problem I am facing is it gets downloaded into downloads folder of computer.

I want to download those file into specific folder.How to do it?

Here is code

```
    $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$stmt);
    $out='';
   $filedate=date("Y-m-d");
 $output='$filedate.NRML_CASH_POSITION_TRADE.csv';

 while ($l = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

  foreach($l AS $key => $value){
    //If the character " exists, then escape it, otherwise the csv file will    be invalid.
     $pos = strpos($value, '"');
     if ($pos !== false) {
        $value = str_replace('"', '\"', $value);
    }
    $out .= '"'.$value.'",';
  }
$out .= "\n";
 }



 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= $output");

echo $out;`
```

Comment: You can't force a download to a certain location. That is set by the user's browser preferences - either it's saved to a preset location, or the user can decide where to save it. This can't be overwritten in PHP.

Comment: Hi Ben, I have seen people setting  path to save output at particular location.somehow i am not able to get it right.

Comment: If you have seen people doing this then please reference that! However, I feel you may have misunderstood as it's simply not possible.

Comment: Okay.thanks for suggestion.

Comment: make a absolute path of your output file, it will download your file to that location. make sure you use an absolute file location.